# Tool to identify binary differences between two files of equal length?

Tags: diff, centos, binaryfiles

I have an application that in effect copies a file and it is sometimes failing to faithfully copy it for some 20MB test files.  I would like to compare the original file to the corrupted ones to see if I can identify any patterns to help me correct the bug in my application. The files are the exact same length.

What is a tool I can run on Centos 4 or 5 that will let me see the differences between these two files at a byte by byte level.  I expect the difference is very small, such as a messed up bit somewhere in the file and I would like to fine the differences and their offset from the beginning of the file. The built in Unix diff utility only says they differ when given binary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`cmp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_%28Unix%29).

```
cmp file1 file2
```